# Django date string translation to english

Tags: django

I am parsing an excel file with dates in it and the date format changes throughout the document. One of the formats is '19 Mart 1912', 'Mart' is the month name in Turkish.

I want to translate this string into English (using Django's builtin translations) as '19 March 1912'.

I tried:

```
 #views.py
    from dataparsers import *
    def getEnglishDate(request)
        translateDateTimeStr('19 Mart 1912')

#dataparsers.py
    from django.utils import translation  
    def translateDateTimeStr(datestr)
         translation.activate('en')
         translatedDateStr = _(datestr)
         translation.deactivate()
         return(translatedDateStr)
```

But nothing changes and I get the same string...

Comment: When are you trying to do the translation? In your view, etc.

Comment: The code is in a function and i am calling it from a view.

Comment: Provide the full code, those snippets are more confusing than helpful

Comment: Ok i have updated with an example code my full code is so long.

Answer (score 0):

It appears Django's [I18N](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) tools has a hard time translating a string with the presence of number characters. I was able to workaround that with the following method:

```
def translateDateTimeStr(s):
    t = []
    w = s.split()
    for s in w:
        translation.activate('de')
        t.append(_(s))
        translation.deactivate()
    return ' '.join(t)

print translateDateTimeStr('12 March 1912')
>>> 12 März 1912

# Does not work
def translateDateTimeStr(s):
    translation.activate('de')
    t = _(s)
    translation.deactivate()
    return t

print translateDateTimeStr('12 March 1912')
>>> 12 March 1912
```

You'll also want to make sure you have `USE_I18N=True` in your settings.py and your `LOCALE_PATH`.

Comment: I have LOCALE_PATHS and USE_I18N = True, but i am still getting the same str not the eng version. My django version is 1.5

Comment: Yes I have tried your code... If the str is '19 March' and in the function i activate 'tr'(which is Turkish) i get correct str as '19 Mart' and your 'de' code is working too but if i use tr string and try to translate it into en it does not work? And in your example if you reverse the logic and give '19 März 2012' to your function and set language as en you can not get en version either...

Comment: And one more thing... If date coming from excel is is '19_Mart_2012' your code will not work either? I think i will create month_tr and month_en name arrays and do replacement... :(